# iPhone SDK - Accessing other Application Folders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file

I know that you can access your own application files using NSDocumentDirectory and such, but can you do that on other applications. For example, if I wanted the Documents of another application, would it be possible to get that information? From the iPhone OS Library as directed [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html).

Sincerely,

Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are limited to accessing files within the application sandbox. A good introduction to this is the "File System Basics" section of the iOS [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide)

Comment: is there any folder there like which can be accessed by all application in the iphone device??????

Comment: The link to this answer has expired do you have an up to date link.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly access the files, however there are a few tricks:

If you are trying to share data amongst a family of apps within the same Wildcard App Id, you can share data via the Keychain.

You can also share data using a custom Pasteboard object.

Of course you can always send data to a server you control.

Another neat trick is saving some data as metadata in the Address Book.

If it is ok, to have some user interaction, you can pass data to another app by launching it the a custom URL scheme.

But, unfortunately direct file access is not allowed.

Comment: is there any common folder there(like documents, music), which can be accessed by all applications in the iphone device??????